# Retrieve all occurrencies from selected attributes to separate column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

want to extract color from the product descriptions. I tried to use NER but it was nt successful. Now I am trying to define a list and match it with description.

I have data in dataframe column like this:

```
Description: Tampered black round grey/natural swing with yellow load-bearing cap
```

I defined also the list of colors

```
attributes =['red','blue','black','violet','grey','natural','beige','silver']
```

What I did was to create a matcher

```
def matcher(x):
   for i in attributes:
       if i in x.lower():
           return i
   else:
       return np.nan
```

And I applied it to the df

```
df['Colours'] = df['Description pre-work'].apply(matcher)
```

The result is horrible too.
I get result:

```
matcher('Tampered black round grey/natural swing with yellow load-bearing cap')

red
```

How can I retrieve all the matches into list and store them in separate column in pandas?
Expected output:

```
['black','grey','natural','yellow']
```

How can I prevent having red as match where there is no red?

I thought I would use

```
findall function
```

to retrieve the data how I want them but also that doesnt help me...

Lost.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jezreel's first answer is very good! however when using

```py
df['Colours'] = df['Description pre-work'].str.findall('|'.join(attributes), flags=re.I)
```

it will always find red when words such as "Tampered " and such
I suggest an easy quick fix (which is not the most robust one) but

```py
def matcher(desc):
    colors = []
    # split sentence to words and find and exact much
    words = desc.lower().replace(';', ' ').replace('-', ' ').replace('/', ' ').split(" ")
    for color in attributes:
        if color in words:
            colors.append(color)
    return colors
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with word boundaries for avoid select `red` in `tempered`:

```
import re
pa = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in attributes)
df['Colours'] = df['Description pre-work'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first split your text into words to avoid the issue of returning "red" for "Tempered". Then you check the intersection of your color list with the split text.

```py
import re

# use a set rather than a list, it will help getting the intersection easily
attributes = {'red','blue','black','violet','grey','natural','beige','silver', 'yellow'}

def get_colors(text: str) -> list[str]:
    # get the word split
    tokens = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text.lower())
    # example tokens: ['Tampered', 'black', 'round', 'grey', 'natural', 'swing', 'with' ...]
    # now simply return the intersection of tokens with attributes, as a list
    return list(attributes.intersection(tokens))

# then apply your function
df['Colours'] = df['Description pre-work'].apply(get_colors)
```

Comment: thank you! sooo much! I will definitely use this one also in the future.